# multiple or single selection

Tags: php, sql

i have two tables and column name are as :

**Table 1**

```
user | food | color | bike | car
```

**Table 2**

```
user | mobile | laptop
```

Now i want to get result by select single or multiple value. 
**For example**, if i want select user which have bike and laptop . then i can get result it by query but for this all fields i have to use many condition . i have used if else where. and i also want to refine select with current selection . so what should i use ? Please help my previous question was same but i did not asked perfectly. so asked again. Thank You.

Comment: Why did you use two tables for this ? One is enough ? Can you elaborate the question a little more ?

Comment: can you post your tables?

Comment: this is sample . if i have this type tables then how can i select.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple tables in your single SQL query. The act of joining in MySQL refers to smashing two or more tables into a single table.

You can use JOINS in SELECT, UPDATE and DELETE statements to join MySQL tables.

**Example**

```
+-----------------+----------------+
| tutorial_author | tutorial_count |
+-----------------+----------------+
| mahran          |             20 |
| mahnaz          |           NULL |
| Jen             |           NULL |
| Gill            |             20 |
| John Poul       |              1 |
| Sanjay          |              1 |
+-----------------+----------------+

SELECT * from tutorials_tbl;
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| tutorial_id | tutorial_title | tutorial_author | submission_date |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|           1 | Learn PHP      | John Poul       | 2007-05-24      |
|           2 | Learn MySQL    | Abdul S         | 2007-05-24      |
|           3 | JAVA Tutorial  | Sanjay          | 2007-05-06      |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+


 SELECT a.tutorial_id, a.tutorial_author, b.tutorial_count
    -> FROM tutorials_tbl a, tcount_tbl b
    -> WHERE a.tutorial_author = b.tutorial_author;
+-------------+-----------------+----------------+
| tutorial_id | tutorial_author | tutorial_count |
+-------------+-----------------+----------------+
|           1 | John Poul       |              1 |
|           3 | Sanjay          |              1 |
+-------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm

Comment: Thank you answer , its useful and have done this. But what if sometimes i have to select only from one table. I have put condition for all fields ,like if this selected then this query but for all field i have wrote many conditions so. I want to any different way like if this value selected then this query automatically check.

Comment: I am sorry but it is not quite clear to me, could you please give an example ?

Comment: table 1- car bike mobile(values : bmw , bullete , iphone) and table 2 - food color (values apple,black). now i have dropdown menu for select value . if i selected first time , iphone from table 1 and black from table 2 then i have to put condition like if this 2 value selected then this query.

Comment: ok I am assuming car, bike, mobile etc are column names ? also what is the output you are expecting

Comment: yes. in result i want to combine like user have iphone and his color is black

Comment: i want to use this for single to multiple values so

Comment: ok , and how table1 and table2 are related ? do you have any id or any such field common in both the tables ?

Comment: "select a.phone,b,color from tbl1 as a join tbl2 as b on a.id=b.id  where id=user_id" will give you black iphone for user_id

Comment: yes u r right but main issue is , if i want to select all column name and some times i will select from table 2 then i have to  use diff query .

Comment: use select * in the query and once you get a complete array , use PHP etc to pick only the values you need